# OpenSTF API POST remoteConnect

Tags: java, rest, post, apache-httpclient-4.x, apache-httpcomponents

OpenSTf has API POST /api/v1/user/devices/{serial}/remoteConnect

I need with Apache http POST send request and pass serial.

```
      HttpPost request = new HttpPost("/api/v1/user/devices/"+ serial +"/remoteConnect");
HttpPost request1 = new HttpPost("/api/v1/user/devices/remoteConnect");

 request.setConfig(config);

                ArrayList<BasicNameValuePair> postParameters = new ArrayList<>();
                postParameters.add(new BasicNameValuePair("serial", serial));

                request.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(postParameters));
```

request  and request1 does not work, I do not understand how to write
API URL in new HttpPost ?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see you sending the access token? Might be the reason why your requests are failing. The access token can be created in the setting section in OpenSTF.

Another issue that might be causing the request to fail is that you don't set the device to a user first.

Note this is my solution and I'm using RestAssured Library to do the POST request.

```
 String AccessToken = "Bearer e334457w44423e2342b6e5b8e5e0e723423488487b5cfe3";
 String BaseUrl = "http://myopenstfapiurl.com/api/v1";
 String deviceserial = "0123456789ABCDEF";

public void SetADeviceToUser() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = BaseUrl;
    RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON).header("Authorization", AccessToken)
        .body("{\"serial\": \"" + deviceserial + "\",\"timeout\": 0}").post("/user/devices")
        .asString();
  }

  public String GetRemoteUrlForDevice() {
    RestAssured.baseURI = BaseUrl;
    String response = RestAssured.given().contentType(ContentType.JSON)
        .header("Authorization", AccessToken)
        .post("/user/devices/" + deviceserial + "/remoteConnect").asString();

    System.out.println(response);
    //Return the remoteConnectURL which will be used to connect to the device. 
    return JsonPath.parse(response).read("$.remoteConnectUrl");
  }
```